# I can't save a photo taken from pictureBox1 in the folder I specified

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

```
 var fd = new SaveFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "Bmp(*.BMP;)|*.BMP;| Jpg(*Jpg)|*.jpg";
      
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName))
            {
                case ".BMP":
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case ".Jpg":
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The function should save the picture with pictureBox in a file but the save window appears. I save but the file simply does not appear in the folder where I saved

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions being raised? Do you have write-access to the folder? Does the file get saved anywhere, just not where you expected?

Comment: If i choose Bmp This write-access.System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference does not point to an object instance."   For some reason, nowhere is it saved.

Comment: Your best friend, the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), should help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obvious thing that I can see is that the switch statement might fall through.

Add the `.ToLower()` when you check the extension and check lowercase extensions.

```
...
...
    switch (Path.GetExtension(fd.FileName).ToLower())
    {
        case ".bmp":
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, ImageFormat.Bmp);
           break;
        case ".jpg":
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(fd.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
...
...
```

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: "The object reference does not point to an object instance." This error appeared.

Comment: Does your picture box show the image? if there is not image in the picture box it will throw that exception.

Comment: Yes indeed. The problem was that although I painted in PicturBox, I did not insert the original image there. Thank you.